# How to update single rows in duplicate entries

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables t1 and t2

t1->

```
id          line        Amt         
----------- ----------- ----------- 
1           1           0
1           2           0
2           1           0
2           2           0
2           3           0
3           3           0
3           4           0
3           5           0
4           2           0
4           3           0

--------------------------
```

t2->

```
id          amt         
----------- ----------- 
1           500
2           350
3           750
4           400
```

In this case I need to update t1 with amount from t2. But I need to update only one row for each id on minimum line. I can do it in MSSQL using the following query-

```
update a set a.amt=c.amt from T1 a inner join (
select id,min(line) line from T1 group by Id) b
on a.id=b.id and a.line=b.line
Inner join T2 c on a.id=c.Id
```

I want to do it in MYSQL. Is there any idea to do something like this

Comment: And what is the problem with this query in mysql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tweak your syntax remove `from` clause, move `set` clause after joins part

```
update T1 a 
inner join (
  select id,min(line) line from T1 group by Id
) b on a.id=b.id and a.line=b.line
inner join T2 c on a.id=c.Id
set a.amt=c.amt
```

[`DEMO`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/68ed0c/1)